# Android Studio doesn't start building Flutter project

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I've installed Flutter, Dart their SDKs and Android Studio plugins everything needed for Flutter app development, as mentioned here:

https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows

But when I go to generate a .apk by selecting *Build->Flutter->BuildAPK*, Android Studio simply does nothing. It doesn't even start building.

However, if I run command:

flutter build apk

It starts building project.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the answer.

*File -> Settings -> Language & Frameworks -> Flutter*

Flutter SDK Path was not set here. When I set appropriate path, it started building.